# How to answer a Jenkins input prompt from slack?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

I'm using the Jenkins slack plugin to send me messages during my automated build. I've set up manual gating, so prod deployments require manual approval. This is done using the Jenkins `input` step.

How can I respond to this `input` step from Slack? Are there any plugins that provide that functionality? I'm not interested in building a slackbot to implement this feature, only an existing Jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the current answer is No. The existing Slack integrations are one directional: Jenkins can use the token to send a message to the Slack app, but Slack has no way to return a result to Jenkins.

Comment: Is it possible then to have those input messages been sent to the slack channel? A simple link to approve the input would suffice, so I can manually click it. Without having Slack talking back to Jenkins itself.